# Insert exactly one space between pattern of one or more characters using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string.

```
'ABCXDEFXABCYXYABC'
```

I want to have them separated by one space. The known patterns in this string are:

```
ABC
X
DEF
Y
```

The resulting string should be

```
'ABC X DEF X ABC Y X Y ABC'

a = 'ABCXDEFXABCYXYABC'
b = a.gsub(/[^ ]\((ABC|DEF|X|Y)\)[^ ]/,' \1 ')
```

I am not having luck with my gsub regex.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's see what you tried already?

Comment: Are you deliberately escaping the outer parentheses?

Comment: @jonnyGold That was to try to capture group 1 for replacement.

Comment: @Anil, the parentheses inside the escaped ones will do that.  Can we see some input example strings, please?  Do they contain parentheses?

Comment: @jonnyGold The input and output I have shown completely describe my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it too complicated:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = 'ABCXDEFXABCYXYABC'
 => "ABCXDEFXABCYXYABC" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > a.gsub(/ABC|DEF|X|Y/, '\0 ').strip
 => "ABC X DEF X ABC Y X Y ABC"
```

Comment: Thanks. btw what is the difference between \0 and \1?

Comment: `\1` gives you the first parenthetical group, like `/(stuff in here) but not this stuff (or this stuff)/` whereas `\0` gives you the entire match, like `/stuff in here (and also stuff in here) (and here)/`. So using `\0` saves you an extra set of parens in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

"@jonnyGold The input and output I have shown completely describe my problem"

Well then,

```
b = 'ABC X DEF X ABC Y X Y ABC'
```

Comment: Just kidding, homes. @Isaac has the solution you actually want  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here'a a solution with [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is what I think you were trying to accomplish in the first place:

```
a.gsub(/(ABC|DEF|X|Y)(?!$)/, '\1 ')
=> "ABC X DEF X ABC Y X Y ABC"
```